# Problems with running String.split("")

Tags: java, string

I have an Integer which I'm trying to convert into a String[] array, so that I can access the individual digits it is comprised of. Here's my code:

```
    Integer num = 101;
    String[] numArray = num.toString().split("");
```

Why does System.out.println(numArray.length) return 4 not 3?

Edit: **To the people downvoting this thread**, if you actually read my post, you would understand that I tried to troubleshoot the issue myself before posting it here. I get that there is a downvote trend here because of exams' week and people seeking easy answers, but I personally wasn't.

Comment: Throw in a breakpoint and see it yourself.

Comment: Yeah I did. The problem is that numArray[0] is equal to a blank space while the indices 1,2, and 3 hold the numbers 1,0,1 respectively. I just need to know why there is a "" at index 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ...

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

However, *leading* empty strings are included. You're splitting on "nothing" which matches *before*  the first character in the string, so you get a leading empty string.

The same thing would occur if you had, for example:

```
String foo = ":a:b:c:";
String[] bar = foo.split(":");
```

`bar[0]` would be an empty string and `bar.length` would be `4`